# jquery flyout menu triangle hover

Tags: jquery, mouseover, flyout

I have built a fly-out menu and have a few problems with mouseover mouseleave mousemove. For orientation I use a triangle for the frist level ( inside the link). Everything works well. If I'm above the link the fly-out opens but when I pass the triangular the menu closing and open again. I do not understand why because the triangle is part of the link.

[here the example](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/JrDUS/3/)

```
<a href="#" class="ml1a">Level 1<span class="arrow"></span></a>

$('.ml1a').mouseover(function(){
var num = this.id.replace('ml1aButton-','');
$(this).parent('li').addClass('ml1liHover');
$('.navMainOverlay').hide();
$('#mainNavOverlay-'+num).fadeIn(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have placed your arrow inside the link with the mouseover effect.

```
<a href="#" class="ml1a">Level 1<span class="arrow"></span></a>
```

It will trigger when you move your mouse over `Level 1` or `<span class="arrow"></span>`.

**Edit**

A few options that comes to mind:

**1)**

Enclose `Level 1` and the arrow in a container, then only add mouseover to `Level 1`. Then you can position the arrow in relation to the container instead of the link.

```
<div><a href="#" class="ml1a">Level 1</a><span class="arrow"></span></div>
```

**2)**

Add stopPropagation to the mouseover event of the arrow. This way everything else will be ignored when moving the mouse over the arrow.

```
$('.arrow').mouseover(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

**3)**

Absolute position the arrow with jQuery. Probably not the way I would go with, but it's an option.

```
$('.arrow').css({top: positionOflink.top + 20, left: positionOflink.left + 50});
```

Comment: So you mean it is a solution to put the span arrow into the div navMainOverlay. But how do i set the triangle under the link?

Comment: Added a few options to my answer.